# Ideas on generating 3D LUTs programmatically?

Tags: math, graphics, datatable, colors

I'm trying to figure out, how to build .3d, .cube or .mga files, which contain look up table data for color correction (e.g. Adobe Lightroom, Davinci Resolve etc.), programmatically. I can't find any hints on how a .cube file is written, structured and/or compiled or which language to use (glsl, c++, python ?). Maybe some of you guys have an idea on how to approach this topic?

Comment: You may check https://www.argyllcms.com/ It is opensource, done by professional (on colour) people, and it support very much hardwares and file formats (.cube is supported).

Comment: Thanks! This seems more like focused on hardware calibration. In concept I will need a sample image, which is compared to a color graded version of it. The color difference between both images should then be stored in a LUT table. But this is exactly the part, of which I have no idea how to approach it. :/

Comment: Yeah, it is a lot about hardware, but I think the concept are not so different. to calibrate a printer, the differenced of measured and expected are calculated, and then put in a LUT (but ih that case not as differences). Also for art reproduction (you have a famous painting, and you want to get on screen as precise as possible. I cannot help more, I'm just a  user.

Comment: You could give a go at pylut: https://github.com/gregcotten/pylut

Comment: So after more research I now know, that I have to search for a way to convert a 2d plotted lut image to a lut table file (like .3d, .cube etc.) If I find something I will post it here!

Comment: Perhaps this can lead some way as well? https://github.com/mikeboers/LUT-Convert

Comment: Haha! I wrote Mike 2 days ago and he could help me out! He also led me to this page https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php You can generate hald images/textures in different resolutions with it. I'm gonna post my results when I find time to try this out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use python **colour science module**.
i am try to convert **sip1d lut** file in **cube lut** file
simple way and use lut file in **pillow** and **pillow_lut module**.you can apply 3dlut in image

```
import colour
from pillow_lut import load_cube_file
from PIL import Image

def convertlut(Inputlutfile:str,outputlutfile:str):
    #read lut file in color modurl
    lut1d = colour.read_LUT(Inputlutfile)
    #Convert 3x1D to LUT3D
    lut3d = colour.io.LUT_to_LUT(lut1d, colour.LUT3D,
    force_conversion=True)
    # Write the cube lut file
    colour.write_LUT(Lut3d, outputlutfile) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    convertlut("cgc_luts\luts\ACEScc_to_linear.spi1d","output3dlut.cube")
    #load lut file
    lut = load_cube_file("output3dlut.cube")
    #open image file 
    im = Image.open("image.png")
    #apply lut object in image and save image
    im.filter(lut).save("image-with-lut-applied.png")
```

i hope this helps. fix your problem

Comment: Thanks! Looks very promising :) Will try it sometime in the future.